# integrating factor for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \omega_\xi - \frac{\omega}{{\xi}} = \xi e^{\xi} $$

I dont understand how to get the integrating factor for this equation,

the answer is $ \frac{1}{\xi} $

how to obtain this? someone please show each step.

thanks

Comment: What should `\omegasub` be? do you want $\omega_\xi$ (`\omega_\xi`)?

Comment: yes thats what i want, sorry

Comment: No problem. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\omega' +\color{blue}{(-1/\xi)}\omega = \xi e^\xi \quad\text{ where } \  ' = {d\ \over d\xi}$$

Then the integrating factor is $$\exp\left(\int \color{blue}{(-1/\xi)} \ d\xi\right) = \exp(-\ln(\xi)) = \boxed{1 \over \xi}$$

Thus

$$\frac{\omega'}{\xi} - \frac{\omega}{\xi^2} = e^\xi$$

or

$$\left(\frac{\omega}{\xi}\right)' = e^\xi$$

Comment: OKay, i understand now, thank you.